# How do I submit multiple pages of user input data from textareas using google forms?

Tags: php, html, forms, google-docs

Right now, I have multiple pages in my website that require user input paragraphs. Basically a quiz, users fill out a paragraph and click next to go to the next page, where they do the same.

I am using google forms to do so. I have taken the  code from the source code. When a user submits one page, the forms record that answer and work fine. However, I'd like one submit button. When I do this, the google forms do not keep the inputs after the user leaves the page.

How can I have google forms on each page of my website and one submit button at the end?

I'm sure there is some way to use php but i'm not familiar with php at all, I'd like to stick with google docs.

```
<div class="page">
    <p>whole bucnh of stuff</p>
        <div class="quesone">
            <p>Question</p>

            <form action="MY-GOOGLEDOC-LINK" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="_self" onsubmit=""><ol role="list" class="ss-question-list" style="padding-left: 0">

                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
                <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item  ss-paragraph-text"><div class="ss-form-entry">
                <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_1389428292"><div class="ss-q-title">ques 1
                </div>
                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div></label>
                <textarea name="entry.1389428292" rows="8" cols="0" class="ss-q-long" id="entry_1389428292" dir="auto" aria-label="ques 1  "></textarea>
                <div class="error-message" id="93637676_errorMessage"></div>
            </div></div></div></div></form>

        </div>

        <div class="questwo">
            <p>Question</p>

            <form action="SAME-GOOGLEDOC-LINK" method="Post" id="ss-form" target="_self" onsubmit=""><ol role="list" class="ss-question-list" style="padding-left: 0">

                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
                <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item  ss-paragraph-text"><div class="ss-form-entry">
                <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_800521984"><div class="ss-q-title">ques 2
                </div>
                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div></label>
                <textarea name="entry.800521984" rows="8" cols="0" class="ss-q-long" id="entry_800521984" dir="auto" aria-label="ques 2  "></textarea>
                <div class="error-message" id="1771597426_errorMessage"></div>
            </div></div></div></div></form>

        </div>
```

This is what my code looks like on each page of my website. Here is what my submit button on the last page looks like:

```
<form action="SAME-GOOGLEDOC-LINK" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="_self" onsubmit=""><ol role="list" class="ss-question-list" style="padding-left: 0">

        <input type="hidden" name="draftResponse" value="[,,&quot;-6067873700707440617&quot;]
        ">
        <input type="hidden" name="pageHistory" value="0">

        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="DpdKrU4BAAA.cBu0TrL7ZVMA6-GJ7Dn4Vw.BBwYcdE16jIxlc5c1a9l3w">
        <input type="hidden" name="fbzx" value="-6067873700707440617">
        <div class="ss-send-email-receipt" style="margin-bottom: 4px;" dir="ltr"><label for="emailReceipt" style="display:inline;"><input type="checkbox" name="emailReceipt" value="true" id="emailReceipt" checked>
        Send me a copy of my responses.</label></div>
        <div class="ss-item ss-navigate"><table id="navigation-table"><tbody><tr><td class="ss-form-entry goog-inline-block" id="navigation-buttons" dir="ltr">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit" class="jfk-button jfk-button-action ">
        <div class="ss-password-warning ss-secondary-text">Never submit passwords through Google Forms.</div></td>
        </tr></tbody></table></div></ol></form>
```

I just want all my data to be submitted on the last page so that when the user submits, they receive only one email containing all their answers from the google forms. If there is any easier way to do this let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is persisting application state across multiple page views.  Since HTTP is by design a stateless protocol, you must use one of several other methods to persist state.  These methods include:

- Session storage
- Cookies
- HTML5 localStorage
- HTML5 sessionStorage
- Passing parameters in URL

Which to use can depend on a lot of factors including information security, whether you need to persist data across sessions, etc.  Unfortunately, the question itself is probably too broad and may be closed, but I at least wanted to give you a better explanation as to why than would be allowed in a short comment.